# Is it possible to create a Slack App that launches a Screen Flow that doesn't require a user to authenticate into Salesforce?

Tags: visual-workflow, slack, slack-salesforce-app, slack-app

I've coded a custom Slack App that leverages a [Slash Command to launch a screen flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_build_invoke_flow_from_shortcut.htm&type=5) in Slack, without the user needing to be in Salesforce or for it to be triggered from Salesforce.

However, in order to leverage the Slack App, the Slack User must connect to their Salesforce account initially.

I'd like to make this app available to non-Salesforce users by leveraging a dedicated "SF/Slack User" to handle the authentication. I have not been able to find any information that confirms if this is possible or not and would like to know if I'm spinning my wheels.

I have the screenflow launching/running perfectly for SF users but need to open up the app to non-SF users as well as there are other functions I'd like to implement.

Has anybody done something similar?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_flow_guestuser.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks for the link but that relates to Guest Users and Salesforce Sites. My issue is removing the authentication process from a Slack App. At the moment, a user can't even reach the flow until they connect their SF account with the Slack App.

Comment: Goal: allow non-Salesforce users to interact with the flow. Proposed solution: remove authentication process from a Slack app. Might be possible but the right solution from the perspective of SF is to publish the flow so that it doesn't require authentication, ergo the link above. Whether Slack can deal with that or it'll require an integration user is a good question.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to do this via an Apex REST resource class.

In a nutshell:

1. Command is invoked via a Slack slash command (custom Slack app)
2. This command is a callout to our Apex REST class
3. REST class fires a Platform Event as well as some other actions, including sending responses to Slack for opening a modal within Slack for user interaction
4. Flow listening for Platform Event performs some action, including using the Slack Post to Channel action to post feedback to the initial invoking channel from Step #1

By using Slack's custom modals and not relying on the Salesforce Slack integration for modal generation, you're decoupling the user from a need for Salesforce auth

Slack refs:
https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands
https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using

SFDC refs:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro.htm